# Laravel 8: Authentication always redirects back to login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect

I recently [shifted](https://laravelshift.com/) a 6-year-old Laravel project from 5.1 to 8.x. I've followed [Upgrading old Laravel applications](https://laravelshift.com/videos/upgrading-old-laravel-applications) and now that I'm running Laravel 8, I can't log into the application anymore. I've rewritten the authentication to match the [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze) starter kit, but my problem remains: After entering the user credentials, I'm always being redirected to the login page.

I double checked if the user really is authenticated by entering wrong user credentials. When doing that, I correctly get an error message. I don't get an error message when entering the right user credentials.

Everything but the login page is only accessible for authenticated users, so these are the relevant portions of my setup:

```php
// /routes/web.php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('login');
});

Route::get('/edit-data', function () {
    return view('dashboard.edit_data');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('edit-data');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

```php
// /routes/auth.php

Route::get('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
    ->middleware('guest')
    ->name('login');

Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
    ->middleware('guest');

Route::post('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->name('logout');
```

```php
// /app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthenticatedSessionController.php

public function create()
{
    if (Auth::check() || Auth::viaRemember()) {
        return redirect('edit-data');
    } else {
        return view('user.login');
    }
}

public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    Session::put('language', LanguageInterface::DE);

    return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}

public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    Auth::guard('web')->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    return redirect('login');
}
```

```php
// /app/Http/Requests/Auth/LoginRequest.php

public function authenticate()
{
    $this->ensureIsNotRateLimited();

    if (!Auth::attempt($this->only('login', 'password'), true)) {
        RateLimiter::hit($this->throttleKey());

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'login' => __('auth.failed'),
        ]);
    }

    RateLimiter::clear($this->throttleKey());
}
```

```php
// /app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

```php
// /app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

public const HOME = '/edit-data';
```

I also debugged the authentication process with Xdebug and noticed that the `path` is correctly set to `/edit-data`. But the outcome is always a refresh of (or redirection to) the login page.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found the solution: The password hashes didn't match anymore. Luckily I had stored the users' credentials and was able to rehash the passwords using `php artisan tinker`:

```php
echo Hash::make('password');
```